# Google Analytics (GA4) setup for tracking Google Workspace Marketplace Add-on views and downloads

Tags: google-analytics, google-workspace-add-ons

Thanks in advance for the answers!
I'm trying to figure out how to tag my google workspace marketplace listing to track pageviews, downloads, etc. with Google Analytics (GA4).
The app page is currently setup for Universal Analytics (UA) which is being depricated on 12/31. I have tried following the setup instructions in Google Analytics for GA4, but the setup manager is not carrying over the tag used for UA.
How do you go about setting up the new tag for GA4 so we can keep getting insights on pageviews for our app listing?

I tried following the setup instrustions in Google Analytics for transitioning from UA to GA4 and was expecting the tag to carry over to the new analytics format. Instead, I am being told to re-tag the website and am not sure how to do that for a google workspace marketplace app listing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same problem and found [this issuetracker article](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/257885701?pli=1), which doesn't sound hopeful (short version: GA4 doesn't appear supported by marketplace - only legacy UA is supported)

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, that's what I'm hearing across the board. We'll see what happens in July.